# Multiple versions of a Com Interop DLL

Tags: c++, .net, com-interop

I have a .NET 2.0 DLL that I build using Com Interop so I can access it from two different C++/MFC applications developed in VS 6.

Currently, one C++ application (App1) uses one form of the .NET DLL (Lib1) and the other one (App2) uses another form (Lib2).  I would like to combine these separate libraries into a single code base (as they should be), but I still need them to be two separate libraries.  However, I don't know how to register these two separate libraries if they have the same name.  Can this be done?  Is there an alternative to what I am currently doing?

App1 accesses its version of the library by calling:
      hr = ::CLSIDFromProgID(L"Lib1.Devices", &clsid);
App2 accesses its version of the library by calling:
      hr = ::CLSIDFromProgID(L"Lib2.Devices", &clsid);

Comment: Use the [ProgId] attribute on your class to alter the name.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.progidattribute.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Two things you can do here

- You can put two different methods for two different forms so that you can have a singe COM object which exposes two methods which can be used by two different applications
- Second thing you can do is, put two different GUID for your com dlls, This way, you can have dll with same name still two different code. It is not recommended though and is the root cause of dll hell.

refer here for this solution
[GUIDs in DLLs (.Net)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489715/guids-in-dlls-net)