# What does the GUID in C# Programs in the AssemblyInfo.cs?

Tags: c#, guid

I'm wondering for what the GUID in the AssemblyInfo.cs in C# Programs is:
`[assembly: Guid("a4df9f47-b2d9-49a9-b237-09220857c051")]`

The commentary says it's for COM objects, but why do they need a GUID?
Is the GUID accessibly externally?

So if it's only for COMs, do you need a GUID when you set `[assembly: ComVisible(false)]`?

Comment: This [question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489715/guids-in-dlls-net) may help you

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Guid (Globally unique identifier) is used to identify your component by outside world. When you write a project which is going to be used as COM (Component Object Model) you will have to give a unique name. For this reason you need to apply GUID attribute.

More info at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.guidattribute.aspx

You can remove it if you won't be exposing it as COM on assembly level

Answer (score 0):

All .Net assemblies have a GUID.

This attribute sets it; otherwise, it will be randomly generated by the compiler.

This GUID is by COM. If your assembly is `ComVisible(true)` then you need a stable GUID, otherwise the compiler will generate a random GUID. You will wonder why things work the first time, but stop working later! You would need to re-register the COM assembly every time with the new GUID.

Comment: Okay - but why do they have one?