# how to fix guid is always showing GUID: {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} in vsto outlook custom add-in?

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I have a custom add-in in outlook which always showing me zero value in event viewer GUID: {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} like this.
this is my code :

```
[Guid("83B5334F-5160-43F3-A9B2-BE1118282F86")]
[ComVisible(true)]
public partial class ThisAddIn
{

 }
```

[image: that's the screenshot of event viewer]

Comment: What you see in log is [assembly guid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22516400/1997232), which can be set with `[assembly: Guid("...")]` in AssermblyInfo.cs. It's not set in your case.

Comment: To get the right GUID you must register the add-in in the Windows registry. It seems you are running the add-in from Visual Studio, not in production, right?

Comment: Eugene yes I am running it in debug mode but I also published it and installed it the isssue remains the same.

Comment: @Sinatr I am also using it in assemblyInfo.cs but same issue

Comment: kindly help me @Sinatr \

Comment: Have you checked [all of those](https://www.google.com/search?q=outlook+addin+guid+site:stackoverflow.com)? I've seen your comment in one of the topics though..

Comment: yeah 
One thing I wanna discuss with you m not seeing my add-in in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\ADDINS in this path ..

Comment: Why does the null guid matter?

Comment: I have a client who is requesting me to add a GUID to my add-in. please Dmirty u have already helped me alot on number of ocassions kindly help me once more